# Check several signals in one String C++

Tags: c++, string

I want to search a position in one string which isn't equal to "(",")","!","&","|",";". If I use `if(str[1] != "!" && str[1] != "(" ...)`, it is too long... is there something I can use to make this simple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're talking about [find_first_not_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/). `str.find_first_not_of("!(...")`.

Answer (score 5):

```
string badChars = "!()&|;";
if ( badChars.find(str[1]) == string::npos )
{
}
```

**Edit**: I think I misunderstood the problem. As Michael Krelin pointed out, [`find_first_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) is probably what you want here.

Answer (score 2):

Any regex engine can match that via:

```
'([^()!&|;])'
```

Comment: ...suggest the right tool for the job? He/she is matching strings, so use a string-matching system known the world over. You can run from regex, but you can't hide.

Comment: @PhilH: Maybe it is parsing and not string-matching. Also it seems the position of this first char is wanted. Not all regex engines provide (easy) access to that information.

Comment: @PhilH: Calling it the "right tool" may underestimate the burden of adding a non-standard or C++11 dependency to the program. Regexes *might* be the right tool for general string-searching needs, but it doesn't follow that they're the right tool for every individual string-searching problem.

Comment: No, true. And @PlasmaHH is right that when the position is wanted, it is more likely parsing rather than matching. As usual, it depends on the context. Adding regex now could be better than writing a load of matching code and then realising you want a negative look-ahead, or to match a digit, or any of the usual 'minor' adjustments to the purpose of a bit of code. Regex does at least make it easy to match the kinds of things people usually want to match. But regex is not lex & yacc...

Comment: @PhilH: I think the real objection is using regexes as an alternative to learning the standard string functionality of whatever language you're using. A regex instead of writing a lot of matching code is a rather different proposition from (as in this case) a regex instead of a standard function. That said, the standard functions of `std::string` are a funny bunch. And of course, some people just don't like regexes at all.

Comment: Very true. I spend more time in Perl, Python, javascript. It is also true that you can spend a lot of time writing a native string matching routine only to end up with something much worse than standard regex will get you. It really depends what you're doing.